# sunspot solr, order results by 'id DESC'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

I'm trying to order my solr results and posts index by date in DESC order but `:order => 'id DESC'` doesn't work

posts controller:

```
def index
   @search = Post.search do
   fulltext params[:search]

    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10

    end
   @posts = @search.results
   # @posts = Post.all
   # @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 17, :order => 'id DESC')


    end
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you referred to https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Ordering-and-pagination  It details how to get data in descending order.

Comment: yeah saw that but not sure how to integrate it

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Ordering-and-pagination , you should be able to pass in an order by of the field.

```
@search = Post.search do
  fulltext params[:search]

  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  order_by(:id, :desc)

end
```

Comment: `No field configured for Post with name 'id'`

Comment: See my answer below, you'll need to update your Post.rb and reindex.

Answer (score 0):

In **Post.rb**, make sure you define:

```
searchable do
  integer :id
end
```

then you will be able to call

```
order_by :id, :desc
```

Solr will need to reindex your data, so make sure you do that too:

```
rake sunspot:solr:stop
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake sunspot:solr:run
```